# como tornar um intervalo de soma dinâmico para incluir apenas os dias de uma dada semana

Tags: dinâmico, google-sheets, soma, calendario, outofrange

Tenho uma tabela (google sheets) que gera dinamicamente, pela escolha do mês, uma folha de calendário formatada com cores diferentes para fins de semana e feriados. pretendo somar as horas semanais, no último dia util de uma semana (coluna `D`), mas sem incluir horas da semana anterior, como está a suceder na figura seguinte. Já consegui que a soma seja efetuada apenas nos dias de sexta feira ou no último dia do mês. Mas como o range que tenho é fixo, acontece o problema que a figura seguinte documenta.

O que necessito é de uma forma de tornar o intervalo de soma dinâmico (a bold na fórmula seguinte), de modo a incluir apenas os dias da presente semana (a coluna `F` contém a data valor de cada dia usada na aplicação da função `fimmês()`.

A fórmula de soma condicional que tenho nas celulas da coluna `D` é a seguinte:

```
=SE(OU(A43="SÁB";A43="DOM");"";SE(OU(A43="SEX";F43=FIMMÊS($F$18;0));**SOMA(C39:C43)**;""))
```

[image: folha de registo de horas mensais/semanais]